# Função Python na AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-aws

Estou precisando rodar a seguinte função abaixo no *AWS Lambda*:

```
def subset_sum(numbers, target, partial=[]):
    s = sum(partial)

# check if the partial sum is equals to target
if s == target:
    print("sum(%s)=%s" % (partial, target))
if s >= target:
    return  # if we reach the number why bother to continue

for i in range(len(numbers)):
    n = numbers[i]
    remaining = numbers[i + 1:]
    subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    subset_sum([1,2,3], 5)
```

Contudo aparece este e não consigo resolver:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "'>=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'LambdaContext'",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
      7,
      "subset_sum",
      "if s >= target:"
    ]
  ]
}
```

A função original tem mais valores que demoram muito tempo por isto estou tentando rodar no *Lambda*. A função retorna a combinação de números que resultam na soma do valor definido (no caso 5)

No computador utilizando `py subset_sum.py` funciona normalmente e retornar 2 e 3 (que combinados é igual a 5).

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

Fiz a modificação conforme resposta do Tom. Agora reporta outro erro.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    s = sum(event['partial'])

    if s == 5:
        print("sum(%s)=%s" % (event['partial'], 5))
        exit()
    if s >= 5:
        return

    for i in range(len(event['numbers'])):
        n = event['numbers'][i]
        remaining = event['numbers'][i + 1:]
        dict = {'numbers' : remaining, 'partial' : event['partial'] + [n]}
        lambda_handler(dict)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dict = {'numbers' : [1,2,3], 'partial' : []}
    lambda_handler(dict)
```

Saída do Lambda

```
{
  "errorMessage": "'partial'",
  "errorType": "KeyError",
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
      5,
      "lambda_handler",
      "s = sum(event['partial'])"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Saída print(event) logo no início do handler

```
START RequestId: f3a45f36-b1fc-11e7-8f6d-d5a3a428a4fd Version: $LATEST
{'key3': 'value3', 'key2': 'value2', 'key1': 'value1'}
'partial': KeyError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 7, in lambda_handler
    s = sum(event['partial'])
KeyError: 'partial'
END RequestId: f3a45f36-b1fc-11e7-8f6d-d5a3a428a4fd
```

Comment: Dica:
Existem ferramentas que simulam um ambiente lambda na tua máquina (ex: serveless framework), usa elas pra testar teu código localmente e depois de testar faz deploy do código no lambda, isso ajuda muito a encontrar erros antes deles ir para a amazon (já sofri bastante com isso).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você definiu a função **subset_sum** como handler da sua Função Lambda, os parametros que são passados são diferentes do seu teste **subset_sum([1,2,3], 5)**.

O invoke do handler recebe os parametros:

- event - Evento responsável pela execução da Lambda Function (API Gateway, CloudWatch e etc);
- context - Informação de runtime.

O erro acontece pela comparação que você está fazendo entre um int e um objeto LambdaContext.

Os parâmetros devem ser acessados através do evento, ex:

```
def my_handler(event, context):
    partial = event['partial']
    target = event['target']

    print(partial)
    print(target)
```

Documentação: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-programming-model-handler-types.html

**EDIT**

---

Pra definir os valores do evento de teste através do console:

Lambda -> (Selecione sua Função Lambda) -> Select a test event -> Configure test events

[image: aws lambda]

Comment: Fantástico Tom! Muito obrigado!

Consegui corrigir corretamente. Agora ainda está dando um errinho pra rodar:

"errorMessage": "'partial'",
"errorType": "KeyError".

Estou investigando.

Comment: Coloque um print do event para ver a estrutura de dados que está chegando no seu handler e veja o log no CloudWatch. Por onde você está chamando a função Lambda? API Gateway ? CLI ? Cron no CloudWatch ?

Comment: Fiz um update na pergunta @tom-melo. Na verdade estou testando a função primeiramente clicando em "Test" diretamente no AWS Lambda.

Comment: coloque um print(event) logo no começo do handler, vai aparecer o log no CloudWatch,

Comment: Show, Tom. Coloquei uma atualização na resposta. Obrigado pelo apoio, é bem importante a resolução desta questão.

Comment: Pelo log não existe a Key "partial", só existe o dict: {'key3': 'value3', 'key2': 'value2', 'key1': 'value1'}, no seu teste você deve passar o JSON que você espera no seu código: { "partial": [], "numbers": [1, 2, 3] }

Comment: Compreendo... O engraçado é que eu chamo ele, olha:

if __name__ == "__main__":
dict = {'numbers' : [1,2,3], 'partial' : []}
lambda_handler(dict)

Comment: Não, digo o "teste pelo console", quando o core do AWS Lambda faz o invoke da sua Lambda Function ele não passa pelo if name == 'main', ele chama apenas sua função handler injetando o envento e o contexto. La no console da aws da um "edit and test" e coloca o input(json) correto.

Comment: Perfeito, Tom. Agora entendi... E onde defino os valores iniciais de event? Desculpes pelas simples perguntas. Tentei definir dentro de Environment. Preciso que seja {'numbers' : [1,2,3], 'partial' : []}.

Comment: Editei a resposta, vê se você consegue encontrar no console da aws.

Comment: Tom... Deu certo!!! São pessoas como você que fazem a diferença!!! Vou detalhar a resposta aqui e no StackOverflow US. Lá não havia consegui uma resposta como a sua. Agora estou entendo o tempo/memória/cpu pra executar a função com a quantidade de termos que preciso. Sucesso!